# Direct ethernet connection to Raspberry PI running Arch linux

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, archlinux, static-ip-address

I need a good tutorial that will explain on how to setup a ssh connection via a direct ethernet connection to a  Raspberry Pi with a static IP running Arch Linux. I have tried a few but all seem to fail. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The Arch wiki is always a good place to start. Take a look at [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#Configuration). As it stands, this question is not appropriate for SO. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

What kind of ethernet connection? Do you have a crossover cable? If yes you can connect it directly to your computer and assign it an IP address. If not, you can connect your Pi to the same router as your computer is connected to, and install *nmap* on your machine. You can run the following command to identify your raspberry pi's IP address (assuming your router assigns IP addresses in 192.168.1.x space):

> nmap -sn 192.168.1.1/24

The Raspberry Pi will show up with its ethernet MAC address and most likely also that the address belongs to RPI foundation. You can then ssh into it.

Comment: Got the same question, but I am stuck at the "assign it an IP address" part. How do I do that?